# PHP after redirect the session variable changes to false

Tags: php, session

I have created a login screen that checks if the password is correct.

After submitting the login form I get to process.php that has these lines:

```
if (password_verify($passwordPost, $passwordDB)) {
        $_SESSION['loged_in'] = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['loged_in'] = false;
    }
    # when I do a print_r on $_SESSION['loged_in'] it results true
    header('Location:  ../../admin/index.php');
```

The index page that checks the session (../../admin/index.php)

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    # when I do a print_r on $_SESSION['loged_in'] here, it results false
    if ($_SESSION['loged_in'] == false) {
        include(PATH_COMPONENTS.'login/index.php'); 
    }
    ?>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Did you start your `session_start();` in `process.php`?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, make sure `session_start();` is loaded in **all** your PHP files, even in `login/index.php`

Comment: No I call it in index.php isn't that enough? or do I need to call the session_start every time I need it?

Comment: @RalphSchipper: the session must be started on every page load, where you would like to access the session data.

Comment: @RalphSchipper Yes you have to start it every time! Otherwise you cannot access it!

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside all your files using sessions and the page(s) you wish to protect, including the same conditional statement, along with an `else{...}` statement, and must be started each time, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start the session in every file! Like this:

```
session_start();  //most times at the top of every file
```

YES, you have to start the session in every file your using it!

Also for error reporting use this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```